# Query - selecting column with same name from 2 tables and comparing it

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm having hard time figuring out how to properly make this query.. So basically, I have following tables:,

```
Table 1,
id | username,

Table 2,
id | someinfo | moreinfo
```

What im trying to do is: print id, username, someinfo, moreinfo where id from table1 and id from table2 are equal.

Note, i'm trying to do this in c++ with mysql lib.

c++

```
std::string query = "SELECT id,username FROM table1 
                    UNION ALL 
                    SELECT someinfo,moreinfo FROM table2 
                    WHERE table1.id=table2.id";


MYSQL_RES* res_set;
MYSQL_ROW row;
mysql_query(connect, query.c_str());
res_set = mysql_store_result(connect);
int numrows = mysql_num_rows(res_set);
int num_col = mysql_num_fields(res_set);

int j = 0;
while (((row = mysql_fetch_row(res_set)) != NULL))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < num_col; i++)
    {
        printf("%s ", row[i] != NULL ? row[i] : "");

    }
    j++;
    std::cout << '\n';
}

mysql_close(connect);
```

I expected the output to print rows, but instead I got exception thrown, and that is probably just a wrong query, because this exact code worked on a more simple query (e.g. SELECT id, username FROM table1)

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: When you UNION to selects, the data type of the columns must be the same in both queries. Yours dont look the same

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems more related to your query than anything else, indeed.

```
std::string query = "SELECT id,username, someinfo, moreinfo 
                     FROM table1
                     JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id"
```

You should read some tutorials [on SQL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be:

```
query = "SELECT table1.id, table1.username, table2.someinfo, table2.moreinfo 
         FROM table1 
             JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.id";
```

Answer (score 0):

The UNION you attempted is syntactically wrong and logically would not produce the results you want. You need a join:

```
SELECT 
  table1.id, table1.username,
  table2.someinfo, table2.moreinfo 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2
ON table2.id = table1.id
```